# !empty() check fails when checking PDO link status... why?

Tags: php, pdo, is-empty

I have the following method inside a class called `Connection`:

```
public function output($query = null) {
    if (!empty($this->attributes["link"])) {
        print "OK!";
    } else {
        print "NO!";
    }
}
```

The value of `$this->attributes["link"]` comes from the following operation in the constructor:

```
try {
    $this->attributes["link"] = new \PDO(<...>);
catch (\PDOException $e) {
    <...>
} finally {
    return $this;
}
```

I normally use the `if (!empty(<...>)) { <...> }` construct to test for variable existence, and it works as expected in every structure or piece of code so far EXCEPT this one.

Being an object doesn't seem to be a reason for this not to work, as I can test the same check against the database manager object, and it works. Maybe the PDO object is a special kind of object not prone to variable testing or is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT** - My software configuration is as follows: Linux 3.11.1, Apache 2.4.6, PHP 5.5.4 and MySQL 5.6.13

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check if is a PDO instance?

```
if ($this->attributes['link'] instanceof \PDO) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Never used the `instanceof` operator in PHP (there's some things about OOP in PHP I haven't really explored yet), so... awesome! My problem isn't solved per se, but I cleaned up the code and now it's even more efficient. Thank you very much! :)